# I don't understand the meaning of "rob them of time"

Tags: grammar, meaning

I don't understand the meaning of this sentense and even how to parse it:

> The American workers **question** what they see as Chinese workers
>   **unquestioned** service to a company that **robs them of time** to enjoy
>   **life**.

1. What does 'question' mean  here?
2. What do 'robs them of time' (specifically, 'them of time') mean?
3. Who are 'them'?
4. Whose 'life'?

I know the meaning of all these words individually, but I don't understand how they fit together in this sentence.

VOA article: Obamas and Netflix Present 1st Joint Film Project, ‘American Factory’
August 23, 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase it:

> The American workers *wonder about* what *the American workers* see as Chinese workers unquestioned service to *Chinese workers' companies* that robs the *Chinese workers* of time to enjoy *the Chinese workers* lives.

1. What does 'question' mean here?

   - "The American workers question" means the Americans wonder about or do not understand why
   - "Chinese workers unquestioned service" means the Chinese workers do not challenge, resent or object to obeying a company.
2. What do 'robs them of time' (specifically, 'them of time') mean?

   - This means that Americans believe the Chinese spend all their time working
3. Who are 'them'?

   - The Chinese workers
4. Whose 'life'?

   - Also the Chinese workers

Comment: Could you explain 'rob them of time' in detail and its grammar.

Comment: Yes it is the same when rob means deprive. I did not know this another meaning of rob with preposition 'of'. I knew that 'rob' is like 'steal' but in rude way and the verb 'to steal' never uses with 'of'.

Answer (score 2):

In a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/222491), you asked: *Could you explain 'rob them of time' in detail and its grammar*.

Think of it as:

> "steal their [free] time from them".

Put another way, we might parse that latter part of the sentence like this:

> [a company that robs them] of [time to enjoy life].

In other words, because the company is demanding such long work hours, we could say that the company is "stealing" their leisure time.

Comment: Could you say just: a company robs/steel their time. It is much more clearly. Why is it clear for native speakers and a big riddle for others, specifically using 'of'' preposition here.

Comment: Yes, one could just write _steals their time_; however, _robs them of their X_ is idiomatic. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=robs+them+of+their+*&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=7) shows that the original wording is often used when talking about "stealing" something abstract, such as time or liberty.

Comment: rob of = deprive of.  I got it.